# Change type of values in deeply nested object structure

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I need to recursively get through the data structure and create a `type` that has some of the fields changed to a different type, based on a condition.

Based on the following structure, I need to create a type (`Result`) where all `A` types are replaced with `B` types.

```
class A{}
class B{}

const data = {
    propA:new AA,
    propB:true,
    nested:{
        propC:new AA,
        propD:false
    }
}

// something like:
type Replace<typeof data, A, B>

// result
type Result = {
    propA:B,
    propB:boolean,
    nested:{
        propC:B
        propD:boolean
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a mapped type, but keep in mind that matching is based on object structure rather than class name, so an object from a `class C{}` will also get converted when you're targeting `A`.

The `Replace` type can be defined as

```
type Replace<T, From, To> = T extends (...args: any[]) => any ? T : {
  [K in keyof T]: 
    [T[K], From] extends [From, T[K]] ? To : Replace<T[K], From, To>
}
```

The first condition is to preserve any methods/function properties as mapped types will convert these to `{}`. The mapped type itself processes each key, and checks whether both value extends the `From` type and the `From` type extends the value type, to ensure equality. If both are equal, the value gets replaced with `To`, and otherwise `Replace` is called recursively.

Here's an example conversion:

```
class A{}
class B{b = 42}
class C{}

const data = {
    propA: new A(),
    propBool: true,
    propC: new C(),
    nested:{
        propA: new A(),
        propBool: false
    },
    f: () => 42
}

type Result = Replace<typeof data, A, B>
// type Result = {
//     propA: B;
//     propBool: boolean;
//     propC: B;
//     nested: {
//         propA: B;
//         propBool: boolean;
//     };
//     f: () => number;
// }
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShYBsCGBjCAeAKgGigMQCcB7AW10yID4oBeKTKCAD2AgDsATAZygAoA6QUgIBzLgC4oSNiADaAXQCUtatJBQA-PSiSA3gFgAUFCiyA0lACWbKAGsIIIgDN68yUZMnZmc-NyFSeUYWdm5TALJ6XyCtCh1YeGQ0LF9-YkiKSiMAXyMjFGQuHgBBXVzDAqQiqAAhXQAjWigAFgAmcsrqgGEyvIqiNi5gKA4kYCQmg2NPMGIwYsk2CAB3KGLeRWwPGbmaoiIESWACAFcILemTWaIwLsWVqC6Ni88oJaGIDnEp19fr%20fuq3Wm22vyg-z2B0kTiQCC4EFBUGyL08TkkGxULVaOT6oEgCS4JwQwzocEQqAweIgzhGYyQuGKuBqWUMAHpWVAqQSiSSoFN2b9-gtagBuIwCv67faHKD1aUQaRitkcyU3O6i8UqzzvVhfPmasE7G7CmpKiWGiHSyRyg4KthmrUmbIO35ovjKGjUNgnEj1CAEF3ZIA)

Comment: Why is it necessary to check that `From` extends `T[K]`?

Comment: @JoeyKilpatrick To avoid also replacing subtypes of `From`. If `From` is `{a: 1}` for example, then without the extra condition it would also replace `{a:1, b:2}`.

Comment: That is certainly a strength of your answer over my own. Also, I had never seen the use of tuples to effectively check multiple `extends` conditions together, very clever. Upvote from me.

Comment: Never knew you could check for multiple extends. Advanced Typescript looks like magic.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with conditional, recursive types:

```js
class A {
    ClassPropA!: string
}
class B {
    ClassPropB!: string
}

const data = {
    propA: new A(),
    propB: true,
    nested:{
        propC: new A(),
        propD:false
    }
}

type Replace<T, A, B> = T extends object
    ? { [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends A ? B : Replace<T[key], A, B> }
    : T;

// type Result = {
//     propA: B,
//     propB: boolean,
//     nested:{
//         propC: B
//         propD: boolean
//     }
//
// }
type Result = Replace<typeof data, A, B>;
```

Comment: This answer is also correct, and it's easier to reason about, however,
I'm going with the @Oblosys answer since it includes that additional check. So just an upvote from me this time.